# Least cost increasing subsequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, binary-search

Say we have an array A that contains N integers. The problem is that we want to minimize the cost of some increasing subsequence(not necessarily strictly increasing) starting at position 1 and ending at position N. The total cost of a subsequence is the total cost of transitioning between elements in the subsequence. When building the subsequence, the cost of transitioning from position j to position i, where i >= j can be found in the matrix COST[i][j]. It is guaranteed that some increasing subsequence exists in which we start from position 1 and reach position N. Values in the array may be very large.

For example:

N = 5

A = [0,3,2,3,3]

Cost =

[[0,INF,INF,INF,INF],

[3,0,INF,INF,INF],

[3,INF,0,INF,INF],

[5,2,2,0,INF],

[6,0,3,1,0]]

The least-cost increasing subsequence is (A[1], A[2], A[5]) or (0,3,3).

The cost
is COST[2][1] + COST[5][2] = 3 + 0 = 3.

So far I have been able to modify the traditional O(n^2) dp solution by initializing dp[i] to infinity and dp[1] to 0 and subsequently looping over all previous values to extend the subsequence. While iterating through previous values I simply maintain the minimum cost.

Now I want to improve this solution and make it o(nlogn). I know the regular LIS problem can be solved using arrays and binary search, but I have been unable to modify such an approach to fit this problem.

Comment: It looks to me more like a graph shortest-path problem than LIS.